# Our Common Bond

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Puzzles are fun
> But we share a ton
> Between and beyond
> Our common bond.

- Concise, memorable, and usually philosophical aphorism
- "You know, sometimes I _____ even myself"
- Mongolian yurt
- Cured meat often eaten at Christmas
- Frozen over
- Ancient Roman night goddess
- Ancient Greek mountain nymph
- Type of daisy found in Minecraft
- Subject or theme
- Wood commonly used to make longbows
- 'The Hunter from the Future' of film
- SI prefix denoting one sextillionth or one trilliardth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> HAPPY NEW YEAR

Individually the answers are

> adage - Concise, memorable, and usually philosophical aphorism
>  amaze - "You know, sometimes I _____ even myself"
>  ger - Mongolian yurt
>  ham - Cured meat often eaten at Christmas
>  icy - Frozen over
>  nox - Ancient Roman night goddess
>  oread - Ancient Greek mountain nymph
>  oxeye - Type of daisy found in Minecraft
>  topic - Subject or theme
>  yew - Wood commonly used to make longbows
>  yor - 'The Hunter from the Future' of film
>  zepto - SI prefix denoting one sextillionth or one trilliardth
>  The answers are in alphabetical order

Now if you

> overlap them you get
>  ham amaze zepto topic icy  => HamAzePtoPicY
>  nox oxeye yew => NoxEyeW
>  yor oread adage ger => YorEadAgeR

Which yields

> Happy New Year if you take only the letters that aren't used twice

And this is indeed

> Between and beyond / Our common bond.