# Snowy, snowy night

Tags: wordplay, visual, graph-theory

[image: snowy_snowy_night]

**Notice that each snowflake is composed of seven hexagons, and each hexagon has a word written clockwise around its perimeter.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The snowflake fills in like this

> [image]
>  forming the words SURTAX, QUORUM, DOUBTS, SKATED, NINETY, CATNIP, & RODENT

How I solved it:

> I started on the right with the X and S and M and Q. I don't believe there are any words where S follows X or where Q follows M so I assumed those two words were of the form **S****X** and **Q****M**. Then it was a matter of finding words that fit those patterns and also have two letters in common represented here by digits: **S12**X** and **Q**21M**. I happen to have a program I wrote while making [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114266/our-common-bond) that does just that. The only words that matched were **SURTAX** and **QUORUM**. I then worked around the snowflake similarly, sometimes having to try all 6 possibilities of word boundary.